# Javascript array returning incorrect value for item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Does anyone know why the following would return the third item's value + 1 rather than just returning the item's correct value?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gz4gA/

```
var items = [10150778347353933, 95698693940, 10151139500303463, 337394396325739, 181838311261, 186661577450, 131239636262, 408877845803303, 130260147046659, 10151850964430652, 190553376302, 256062744215, 73099117435, 30571361895, 85358203371, 133621058800, 67899501771, 422515109312, 56271008850, 107997326726, 382312857465, 144163385597840, 10150882307310061, 184244804960462, 63953746442, 114588455254586, 201992215550, 401799715673, 287217811299764, 96668113887, 106824841365, 130084127023410, 186061480932, 60351005403, 209693813195, 10150593297330601, 319622191193, 68686268942, 290590784383, 63467856465, 470235003273, 127564720953, 127437064077, 102351319089, 113530295368, 82102942060, 290699835908, 81445359355, 137490940846, 119104781632, 415115129332, 120520318032430, 142666108227, 146711457500, 344723925588563, 239108779476988, 121853939741, 109322101963, 54456613147, 473850413696, 10150329755772674];
console.log(items[2]);
```

​

Comment: Possibly exceeded the maximum integer that javascript can represent?

Comment: Item codes are better represented as strings.  Saves the problem of leading zeroes disappearing as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point values. The largest integer value that can be represented exactly is 2<sup>53</sup>, or 9007199254740992. Numbers larger than that (including the 3<sup>rd</sup> element of your array) are represented only approximately. See, for instance, [ECMA 262-5, section 8.5](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and explanation!

Comment: That isn't the largest integer value that can be represented exactly, see [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3.2).

Comment: @RobG - Well, yes, some larger integers can be represented exactly. That was poorly worded. What I should have said was that it was the largest of the range integers _without gaps_ that can be represented. Beyond that, you begin to find integers that cannot be represented. (Note, for instance, that `Number.MAX_VALUE - 1` is not representable in JavaScript. `console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE == (Number.MAX_VALUE-1))` will print `true`.)

Answer (score 2):

Per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/816620, the top of the range where javascript can represent all integers is: `9007199254740992` which is smaller than your `10151139500303463`.  So, your number is too large.

If these are something like item codes rather than something you really need to use as a number, then perhaps you should store them as strings, not as numbers.

Comment: That isn't correct. The sequence of **continuous** integers that can be represented exactly is -2^53 to +2^53. There are many more that can be represented exactly, but they aren't continuous. The largest integer is given by [Number.MAX_VALUE](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3.2), which is `approximately 1.7976931348623157 × 10^308`, and [`Number.MIN_VALUE`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.3.3), which is `approximately 5 × 10^‑324`.

Comment: @RobG - Rob, you're being kind of technical here and not really addressing the context of the OP's question. Max integer in this context means the OP's integer is beyond the range where javascript can represent any integer exactly.